# How to run Future/await with Timer.periodic in flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await, timer, future, periodic

i want running
next step

1. mainTimerStart run
2. after 2sec
3. print 'Fist Timer End'
4. mainTimerStart run
5. after 3sec
6. print 'Second Timer End'

But.... now
All the step work at once.

look at my code

button function code

```
onPressed: () async {
  await timeSetController.mainTimerStart(2);
  print('First Timer End');
  await timeSetController.mainTimerStart(3);
  print('Second Timer End');
},
```

mainTimerStart function code

```
Future<void> mainTimerStart(int setMainTime) async {
  isMainTimerRun(true);
  time(setMainTime);
  mainTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
    if (time <= 1) {
      mainTimer?.cancel();
      time(0);
      isMainTimerRun(false);
    } else {
      time--;
    }
  });
}
```